# How does using more than 10 bins/buckets work for Radix sort?

Tags: sorting, radix-sort

Hi guys I only just learned Radix sort today, and every resource only shows using Radix sort with a decimal base. Every resource I've seen demonstrates taking the last digit of each number in the list you are sorting and placing them in a bin from 0-9 based on this digit.

I was wondering if anyone had any basic examples of a base greater than 10 because I don't get how you would be able to put numbers into double digit bins according to their last digit. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of thinking "the last digit", think "modulo n".  So if you want, say, 23 buckets, then put each number into bucket (number % 23)

Comment: Thanks a lot! When you say 'number % 23', which number would this be? The single digits from lowest significant value to highest one by one?

Comment: The number is your "each number in the list".  For example, if your list contained the number 386, then that 386 would go into bucket (386 % 23) = 18

Comment: Link to [example of base 256 radix sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350577/radix-sort-base-16-hexadecimals/40353123#40353123) .