# What's the most performant way to create a sorted copy of a C++ vector?

Tags: c++, sorting, stdvector

Given a C++ vector (let's say it's of doubles, and let's call it `unsorted`), what is the most performant way to create a new vector `sorted` which contains a sorted copy of `unsorted`?

Consider the following naïve solution:

```
std::vector<double> sorted = unsorted;
std::sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end());
```

This solution has two steps:

1. Create an entire copy of `unsorted`.
2. Sort it.

However, there is potentially a lot of wasted effort in the initial copy of step 1, particularly for a large vector that is (for example) already mostly sorted.

Were I writing this code by hand, I could combine the first pass of my sorting algorithm with step 1, by having the first pass read the values from the `unsorted` vector while writing them, partially sorted as necessary, into `sorted`. Depending on the algorithm, subsequent steps might then work just with the data in `sorted`.

Is there a way to do such a thing with the C++ standard library, Boost, or a third-party cross-platform library?

One important point would be to ensure that the memory for the `sorted` C++ vector isn't needlessly initialized to zeroes before the sorting begins. Many sorting algorithms would require immediate random-write access to the `sorted` vector, so using `reserve()` and `push_back()` won't work for that first pass, yet `resize()` would waste time initializing the vector.

---

**Edit**: As the answers and comments don't necessarily see why the "naïve solution" is inefficient, consider the case where the `unsorted` array is in fact already in sorted order (or just needs a single swap to become sorted). In that case, regardless of the sort algorithm, with the naïve solution every value will need to be read at least twice--once while copying, and once while sorting. But with a copy-while-sorting solution, the number of reads could potentially be halved, and thus the performance approximately doubled. A similar situation arises, regardless of the data in `unsorted`, when using sorting algorithms that are more performant than `std::sort` (which may be O(n) rather than O(n log n)).

Comment: Copy first, then sort the copy.  The `std::vector` has an efficient copy method.

Comment: Naïve solution's pretty solid in this case.

Comment: below link is not general algorithm, but worth to read. https://probablydance.com/2016/12/27/i-wrote-a-faster-sorting-algorithm/

Comment: It would be nice if a `insertion_sort` method is added in the STL so that this task can be done in a nice way.

Comment: Are you asking for general case correctness, or can we assume particular things to be more performant?

Comment: You can create a sorted "view" of the vector without copying by creating a new sorted vector of `std::reference_wrapper`s.

Answer (score 10):

The standard library - on purpose - doesn't have a sort-while-copying function, because the copy is O(n) while `std::sort` is O(n log n).

So the sort will totally dominate the cost for any larger values of n. (And if n is small, it doesn't matter anyway).

Comment: While `std::sort` is O(n log n) in the general case, it isn't for all possible input values. Consider data that is almost entirely sorted but only two values need to be swapped: "sort-while-copy" would be roughly twice the speed of "copy-then-sort." Similarly, consider linear-time sorting algorithms, such as a [radix sort](http://stereopsis.com/radix.html) or a [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort). Boost contains [spreadsort](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/sort/doc/html/index.html), which works with integers and floats, but requires an initial copy operation.

Comment: If you have *very* specific knowledge of your data, you can of course often do something better than the general algorithms. If you *always* have exactly two elements out of order, you could for example swap those, use the sorted array as input to some function, and then swap them back again. That might be even faster. But, no, the standard library doesn't have something like that. And if you have this specific knowledge, using `std::sort` might be the worst choice as it can reach O(n^2) for already sorted data.

Comment: @JohnSpeeks radix sort and bucket sort don't generalise to arbitrary data. In the domains I've worked in, they've never even been *applicable*.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the vector of doubles doesn't contain special numbers like NAN or infinity, then the doubles can be treated as 64 bit sign + magnitude integers, which can be converted to be used for a radix sort which is fastest. These "sign + magnitude integers" will need to be converted into 64 bit unsigned integers. These macros can be used to convert back and forth SM stands fro sign + magnitude, ULL for unsigned long long (uint64_t). It's assumed that the doubles are cast to type unsigned long long in order to use these macros:

```
#define SM2ULL(x) ((x)^(((~(x) >> 63)-1) | 0x8000000000000000ull))
#define ULL2SM(x) ((x)^((( (x) >> 63)-1) | 0x8000000000000000ull))
```

Note that using these macros will treat negative zero as less than positive zero, but this is normally not an issue.

Since radix sort needs an initial read pass to generate a matrix of counts (which are then converted into the starting or ending indices of logical bucket boundaries), then in this case, the initial read pass would be a copy pass that also generates the matrix of counts. A base 256 sort would use a matrix of size [8][256], and after the copy, 8 radix sort passes would be performed. If the vector is much larger than cache size, then the dominant time factor will be the random access writes during each radix sort pass.

Comment: I am indeed aware of this trick, and it's a good one, and I am indeed familiar with sorting implementations that use it (see my comment on @BoPersson's answer). Unfortunately, this doesn't help with the issue of that wasteful initial copy while using the Standard Library, since all the implementations I can find seem to be sort-in-place. I am essentially looking for a pre-written sort implementation that would work the lines of `std::vector<double> sorted = fast_sorted_copy(unsorted);` so that I don't need to roll my own.

Comment: @JohnSpeeks - I'm not aware of a standard library implementation of radix sort. The first pass could read, convert, write and also create a matrix of counts that get converted into indices. [example of radix sort base 256](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350577/radix-sort-base-16-hexadecimals/40353123#40353123)

Answer (score 1):

There is std::partial_sort_copy() in <algorithm>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).